# Обход и вывод многомерного массива

Tags: php

Есть массив:

```
Array
(
    [title] => Array
        (
            [0] =>                      Mortal Kombat X          
            [1] =>                      Mortal Kombat 2   

        )

    [desc] => Array
        (
            [0] => 489
            [1] => 32
        )

    [metatitle] => Array
        (
            [0] => 34
            [1] => 4

        )

    [date] => Array
        (
            [0] => 17.02.2017
            [1] => 17.02.2017

        )

    [magnet] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://site1
            [1] => http://site2
        )

    [torrent] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://site1
            [1] => http://site2

        )

)
```

Мне нужно сделать цикл и вытащить по 1 значению с 0 индексом, потом увеличить счетчик и еще раз пройти. Я знаю цикл for, но не могу разобраться с фореч. Тут неизвестно конечное число элементов в массиве. Поэтому нужно с нуля начинать и выводить до тех пор, пока не кончится.

**Алгоритм такой:**
1 цикл прохода должен дать такой результат:

> Mortal Kombat X | 489 | 34 | 17.02.2017 | http://site1 | http://site1

Затем счетчик увеличивается и вытягиваются данные под индексом 1.

Как сделать такое? Не могу побороть пока-что фореч.

Comment: так тут и не нужен `foreach`, можно также `for` с двумя проходами. `for($i = 0; $i < 2; ++$i) { echo $array['title'][$i] .', ' . $array['desc'][$i] . '<br/>'; }` ...... если неизвестно сколько проходов должно быть, то достаточно взять `$count = count($array['title']);`

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего как-то так:

```
<?php

$arr = array(
  'title' => array('Mortal Kombat X', 'Mortal Kombat 2'),
  'desc' => array(489, 32),
  'metatitle' => array(34, 4),
  'date' => array('17.02.2017', '17.02.2017'),
  'magnet' => array('http://site1', 'http://site2'),
  'torrent' => array('http://site1', 'http://site2')
);
$newArr = array();

foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
  for($i = 0; $i < count($val); $i++) {
    $newArr[$i][$key] = $val[$i];
  }
}

print_r($newArr);

/*
*  Array (
*    [0] => Array ( [title] => Mortal Kombat X [desc] => 489 [metatitle] => 34 [date] => 17.02.2017 [magnet] => http://site1 [torrent] => http://site1 )
*    [1] => Array ( [title] => Mortal Kombat 2 [desc] => 32 [metatitle] => 4 [date] => 17.02.2017 [magnet] => http://site2 [torrent] => http://site2 )
*  )
*/

for($i = 0; $i < count($newArr); $i++) {
  echo implode(' | ', $newArr[$i]) . '<br/>';
}

/*
*  Mortal Kombat X | 489 | 34 | 17.02.2017 | http://site1 | http://site1
*  Mortal Kombat 2 | 32 | 4 | 17.02.2017 | http://site2 | http://site2
*/
```

Comment: Неправильно поняли меня. У меня уже есть массив. В начале указана его структура.  Конечное количество элементов неизвестно, потому как оно будет постоянно разное. Поэтому нужно проходить с помощью фореч.

Comment: @LEX, ну так оно и проходит через `foreach`, потом забирает все значения и вставляет в новый массив, в конце приведен финальный массив который получается, что бы сделать то что у вас описано как "ожидаемый результат" вам лишь надо пройтись в цикле по `$newArr` и заимплодить каждый подмассив.

Comment: @MedvedevDev ТС'у наверное нужно что-то типа этого: [песочница](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b6f393c03b2c34cca73bc3f7a608c0bd6aa0eb10)

Comment: @Эдуард, нам остается лишь гадать xDD

Comment: То, что нужно. И гадать не нужно :) Я и так все детально описал :)

Comment: @LEX, "То, что и нужно" ... в песочнице ровно то же самое, что и в ответе, но ответ вас чем-то не устраивал ... может вы и описали неплохо задачу, но в итоге не поняли, что решение вам дали.